# How do you switch between two different Xamarin Form pages?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to figure out how to switch between two different pages in Xamarin Forms.

I *do not* wish to use a `NavigationPage` (which has that little *back* arrow that is auto displayed.

I have a Login page (which is a `ContentPage`) and once the person has authenticated, I then need to navigate to my Dashboard page (which is a `TabbedPage`).

eg.

[image]

Next, one of the Tab's in the TabbedPage is the profile of the logged in user. As such, I need to log them out. So i'll have a button to log them out, which means I will need to navigate them back to the Login page (which was that `ContentPage`).

[image]

I feel like I have two *modes* the user might be in.

- UnAuthorized. (`ContentPage`)
- Authorized. (`TabbedPage`).

It's like I need to change the `App`'s `MainPage` to be either one of those two?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To change MainPage to another just do:

```net
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyContentPage());
```

or

```net
App.Current.MainPage = new MyContentPage();
```

BTW: You can use a NavigationPage and then HIDE the toolbar with:

```net
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do navigation as usual by setting MainPage in your Application instance. Small sample.

```net
namespace TestNavigation
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App ()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            MainPage = new MyPage1 ();
        }
    }
}


namespace TestNavigation
{
    public class MyPage1 : ContentPage
    {
        public MyPage1 ()
        {
            var button = new Button () {
                Text = "Click me"
            };
            button.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                Application.Current.MainPage = new MyPage2 ();
            };
            Content = new StackLayout { 
                Children = {
                    button
                }
            };
        }
    }
}


namespace TestNavigation
{
    public class MyPage2 : ContentPage
    {
        public MyPage2 ()
        {
            Content = new StackLayout { 
                Children = {
                    new Label { Text = "Hello ContentPage" }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT1**

I submitted this answer but then I realised that I probably don't understand your problem.

**EDIT2**

Updated sample.

Comment: Sorta - you did explain how to set the `MainPage` to be 2x different Pages ... but I was looking for a more complex solution that does this, where the different pages are in different classes, etc.

Comment: Still I don't understand the problem. Updated the sample to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to switch between the pages then you can simply do

```
Application.Current.MainPage=new YourPage();
```

[How to Change MainPage in xamarin forms at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137474/how-to-change-mainpage-in-xamarin-forms-at-runtime)

this is what i have done to get result

Answer (score -1):

For a login page, the best practice is to use

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync (new LoginPage());
```

Once you are on the LoginPage, you can use popModelAsync after the validation is passed:

```
await Navigation.PopModalAsync ();
```

Comment: Not really a "Best Practice" it is often done but it causes other issues. IE You dont have the User or thier Role to make decisions you may need to load the mainpage. Granted you can work around it but it generally just feels dirty.