# How to Change MainPage in xamarin forms at runtime?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-mobile-services, xamarin.forms

In xamarin forms,RootPage with master detail Layout.  My task is to  show that page after user successful login. I am using azure mobile service for login. I spend more time to get result.I saw some other solutions but those solution does not render master detail as expected.Finally i got  the solution.

Here is the code in app.cs

```
public App()
    {

     Client = new MobileServiceClient("your azure url", "your master key");
        LoadMainPage();

    } public void LoadMainPage()
    {
        if (Client.CurrentUser == null)
        {
            MainPage=new NavigationPage(new SplashPage());
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage = new RootView();;
        }


    }
```

In Login page

```
 async void  OnLoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MobileServiceUser user;

        try
        {
            user = await DependencyService.Get<IMobileClient>().LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
            Application.Current.MainPage=new RootView();
            await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.Contains("Authentication was cancelled"))
            {
                //messageLabel.Text = "Authentication cancelled by the user";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          //  messageLabel.Text = "Authentication failed";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to look at doing navigation, not changing the routes for these paths. Take a look at the Xamarin Navigation docs here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Navigation

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice point! This way, I can navigate to my Login page whenever I get a webapi AccessToken Expired.