# Navigation Stack Destroyed after onResume()?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-lifecycle

I'm having a odd experience with the onResume() in my app

Here's a small Screen recording(not sure how to post it here) 
https://vimeo.com/387615558?ref=em-share

Here is a Sample project to Recreate the Issue
https://github.com/Lirian21/SampleApp

I get breakpoints to stop and I get the Method to run but for some reason, It doesn't actually pop to the root,

And if I do get the navigation to actually work it just navigates to a dead page and the app just freezes up.
I'm not actually sure how to handle the onResume() atm, The only things I need to happen is that it needs to check if theres a connection and if there is that it should just go to the home page, I'd prefer if it just continued where it left off but not to sure how that works.

```cs
protected override void OnResume()
{
    try
    {
        MakeWebRequest();
        if (IsConnected != true)
        {
             MainPage = new NoInternet();
        }
        else
        {
               //base.OnResume();
            var nav = MainPage.Navigation;

            nav.PopToRootAsync(true);

            nav.PushAsync(new Home("XXXX"));
        }

    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {

        Crashes.TrackError(ex);
    }

}
```

```cs
public partial class Home : MasterDetailPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

```cs
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MakeWebRequest();

    try
    {

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Home("XXXX"));
    }
 }
```

Also I do not have the setting on my Phone to Destroy Activities Enabled

I found a Constant in the log weather onResume(), OnStart() ect But I cant seem to find what the error means

```
[HwSecImmHelper] mSecurityInputMethodService is null
```

Update:

I have found that the Application Doesnt Crash like ive shown If I Navigate using a Button on a Product and then using the Master Detail Navigation

So The Application only Crashes when i'm Using the Master Detail page navigation directly after resuming

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Xamarin, but you must call through to the super class' implementation of `onResume()`. You aren't doing that here (unless Xamarin is doing that for you).

Comment: Added a link to a short clip with whats happening, As far as I understand thats what the ```base.OnResume();``` is for but results are the same

Comment: Would it work if you remove nav.PushAsync(new Home("XXXX"));? Why are you want to push to a new HomePage when you get a HomePage after PopToRootAsync.

Comment: I just posted everything I used, Its the same result regardless if I just push to Root same, If I Push a new home Same, Nothing but the try catch same thing not sure whats happening, But I was using the PoptoRoot to clear the Stack Wanted to then navigate to the page i was on but Decided to first figure this out

Comment: Can you please provide us a sample project which can reproduce this issue?

Comment: I'll make on quick and try and keep as much of my original code in there I'll just comment stuff out so you guys can still see what I was using. Just waiting on a update on my Mobile device. Then ill run it and see if I can reproduce

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I added a Sample project for you

Comment: I don't see any page or the app freezes after calling onResume method with your  sample project? Am I miss something?

Comment: Really? I've tested that on my Device and 3 Emulaters Pixal 2 Pixal 3 and Nexus 10, And I get the same Result as the Clip I posted If I Put the app in background, Open it and Use the menu to navigate anywhere its just a blank page with no response. And when you see you dont see any page? you Dont see the Master-detail Navigation I just added login and home so u have something to navigate between

Comment: Not sure about the reason that page comes blank. But how about popup a connection dialogue or ```nav.PushModalAsync(new NoInternet());``` instead of manipulating MainPage

Comment: And a bit wired that HomePage is a MD page not MainPage, in which case ```MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Home("The Title Changed"));``` makes more sense. Actually, I found that the title was not updated (after I fixed the title binding), which means the navigation stack might be stuck in the previous page.

Comment: Similar Q for [manipulating Mainpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137474/how-to-change-mainpage-in-xamarin-forms-at-runtime)

Comment: @Shaw Its like you say I think the navigation stack is getting mangled somehow, I've been testing non stop and I found a interesting interaction, If I make the Request on Start app and End up on the noInternet() Page And I Sleep/Resume the Activity as many times as I want and I use the button to test my Connection and I Navigate using ``` Application.Current.MainPage = new Home();``` It Actually works fine, Issue is It doesnt Trigger my Navigation on Resume So if I I actually get it to break at something like ```MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Home("The Title Changed"));``` In onResume()

Comment: @Shaw It Actually Breaks but doesnt do anything it doesnt navigate thus why I think the Navigation stack is getting destroyed and yeah I kinda messed up making home the MD, I just have no idea what i'm doing wrong here I cant find any Solid Documentation on what your actually suppose to do in the onResume and OnSleep besides Maybe persist some properties/Bindings

Comment: @Someguy seems like [a xf issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7400#issuecomment-557187096)

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing the `async`+ `await` keywords.

If you're interested in learning why we need the `async` and `await` keywords, I recommend watching this presentation I recently gave on async/await, explaining how it works in .NET: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0mcYVxJEl0

```cs
protected override async void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();

    try
    {
        MakeWebRequest();

        if (IsConnected != true)
        {
             MainPage = new NoInternet();
        }
        else
        {
            await MainPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync(true);

            await MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Home("XXXX"));
        }

    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Crashes.TrackError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah How I wish this resolved it for me, However the results are the same, I get the application to launch but the second I navigate it just navigates to a blank "Dead" Page and the app is basically killed , I will take you up on watching that presentation tho, Also note I tried Changing the navigation i'm using here around aswell

Comment: I also dont get it to actually navigate to the noInternet view, So i'm not sure whats happening